# Android View animation show slide left and hide slide right

Tags: android, kotlin

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">
    
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want show hide my fragment

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the navigation component, as mentioned in [this guide by Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). You can do this with ease. Once you set up your fragment container and navigation graph. You need to create two anim files for `slide_right` and slide_left and set those values in nav graph file.

This is the slide_right.xml file to add the slide left to right animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

This is the animation file to add the inverse animation of sliding right to left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

In your navigation graph file in the action tag, you should add something like this.

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_explore_to_map"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentMapView"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
```

You are good to go. This is the recommended way of doing the transition animation in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

With the navigation component.
First, make an animation package in res by creating an Android Resource Directory.

Second, you should have 4 files: from_right , to_left, from_left , to_right

from_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

to_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

from_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

to_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

Now u should open your nav_graph.xml, click on the destination you want by simply clicking the arrow that links both fragments. Go to attributes, open Animations
then you set

```
enterAnim -> @anim/from_left 
exitAnim -> @anim/to_right
popEnterAnim -> @anim/from_right
extiEnterAnim -> @anim/to_left
```